# When can you form the comparative of 'sorry'?

Tags: comparatives

Is *sorry* in the phrase “I’m sorry” an adverb or an adjective?
In other, more practical words, is a comparative response to that, such as “Sure, but I’m even sorrier!”, considered grammatically correct?

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond what's found in the [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sorry)? If so, you should edit.

Comment: Bear in mind: A sorry-looking fellow.

Comment: It appears in the fixed formula _A sorrier bunch of ...... I've never seen!_

Answer (score 2):

"Sorry" is an adjective.

In the context of the phrase "I'm sorry" it means "regretful, apologetic". Therefore, an answer like "I'm even sorrier" would probably mean that one is more regretful or feels he should be the one to apologise. It is grammatically correct.

Comment: Hello, Sanya. Please  take the site 'tour' and look at a few questions to gauge the standards considered appropriate  on ELU (aimed at more seasoned Anglophiles/linguists). 'Sorry is a predicate adjective here, after the copula; comparatives are 'sorrier' and 'more sorry', the latter more usual' and 'I'm sorrier' sounding subtly off here are probably all ELL level. Butt OP needs to add their own research in any case.